# DirectShow Runtime Encoder H264

Tags: c#, camera, h.264, directshow.net

I have already used DirectShow.NET to display alive webcam,now I need while the webcam is working to encode the video **using H264** then write/Append it on the desk after x time.

I have already found a [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/files/DirectShow/DirectShowFilters/H.264/) for H264 using directShow contains Encoder and decoder but when I try to insert it I got this error (image shown below)

[image]

**So My questions are:**

1. Does anyone have idea about the error message
2. if this way will not work is there any other library to use to have H264 with direct Show(without needing to wrap)

Answer (score 0):

VS is telling you that you cannot add reference to h264 because it is not assembly or COM component. And you don't have to.

These are DirectShow filters that need to be registered on your system (using regsvr32) and then you can instantiate and add them to your filter graph using only their GUIDs.

If you need to access custom interfaces on them, to change encoding parameters or similar, then you'll have to translate interfaces into your managed language. (You can probably find interface definitions in VideoProcessing source code).